# How do I fix pin assignments on a Quartus Prime Lite project?

Tags: quartus-ii, soc, quartus

I am using Quartus Prime Lite Edition 16.02 and am trying to fix messed-up pin assignments for a simple project with a single verilog file:

```
module mux4( input  a, b, c, d,
             input [1:0] sel,
             output out );
  wire t0, t1;
  assign out = ~( (t0 | sel[0]) & (t1 | ~sel[0]) );
  assign t1  = ~( (sel[1] & d) | (~sel[1] & b) );
  assign t0  = ~( (sel[1] & c) | (~sel[1] & a) );
endmodule
```

In the past, I've assigned nodes `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `sel[1]`, and `sel[0]` to SW[0], SW[1], SW[2], SW[3], SW[4], and SW[5], respectively, and I've assigned node `out` to LEDR[0]. Since changing the verilog file, however, I've been unable to get pin assignments to work.

I tried the following:

1. I deleted the `.qsf` file from the project directory (through the
   file system).
2. I selected `Assignments > Import Assignments` and imported
   [DE1_SoC.qsf](ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Altera_Material/Boards/DE1-SoC/DE1_SoC.qsf).
3. When I open the assignment editor, the pins to which I had assigned nodes show up with question marks in their status column: [image]
   In the bottom of the assignment editor, I see my earlier pin assignments: [image]
4. I start a compile.

I get these messages:

```
Info (171003): Fitter is performing an Auto Fit compilation, which may decrease Fitter effort to reduce compilation time
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license. You can purchase a software subscription to gain full access to this feature.
Error (171016): Can't place node "c" -- illegal location assignment PIN_AF9
Error (171016): Can't place node "b" -- illegal location assignment PIN_AC12
Error (171016): Can't place node "d" -- illegal location assignment PIN_AF10
Error (171016): Can't place node "sel[1]" -- illegal location assignment PIN_AD12
Error (171016): Can't place node "sel[0]" -- illegal location assignment PIN_AD11
Info (11798): Fitter preparation operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Warning (171167): Found invalid Fitter assignments. See the Ignored Assignments panel in the Fitter Compilation Report for more information.
Error (11802): Can't fit design in device. Modify your design to reduce resources, or choose a larger device. The Altera Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error: Quartus Prime Fitter was unsuccessful. 6 errors, 3 warnings
```

I was able to simulate this design in the past. What do I need to do to get it working again?

Comment: Have you selected the correct device? Assignments/Device

Comment: @Icy Thank you. Setting the board through that menu, then repeating the steps fixed the problem. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it correct. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may not have the right device selected.

Check and set the device from: Assignments/Device